# Example for the RAML file in Anypoint studio

Tags: maven, raml, anypoint-studio

I currently follow this tutorial: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/creating-an-apikit-project-with-maven but I have a problem in creating the RAML file I don't know how to do this and I have to take the information from these two APIs:
• http://www.programmableweb.com/api/wikipedia
• http://www.programmableweb.com/api/weather-channel

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Title
version: 1.0
baseUri: http://server/api/
schemas:
  - Countries: |
      {
        "$schema": "which link",
        "type" : "",
        "properties" : {
          }
      }
```

Is Schemas what  need to use?
The final goal is to create an API giving some information about cities and countries. In order to do that, I need to communicate with some others API providers (the two links above) toobtain information and craft the JSON response to return the required information..

Comment: Actually you don't need a schema, it's optional. You have to specify the resources [link] (https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#resources-and-nested-resources) with the supported operations (put, get, post, etc) and the responses of each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAML is the contract of the RESTful API you want to expose. So, first you need to understand how to code a **RAML**:

> http://raml.org/

Then you can use the component **APIKit** in Anypoint Studio that generates the flows based on your RAML.

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/apikit-tutorial

After that you will want to connect to third party APIs like wikipedia or weather channel. For that you can use the **HTTP Request Connector** if those APIs are REST.

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-request-connector

If those APIs are SOAP based you have to use the **Webservice Consumer** component, that automatically infers the content of the wsdl and you can choose wich method to invoke, and set the necessary parameters.

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer

To do the transformations from your received data to the third party APIs data, you should use **Dataweave**

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave

I also recommend the walkthrough tutorials, for designing, building and deploying a new API.

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/anypoint-platform-for-apis-walkthrough